weak-* convergence does not imply weak convergence
I wish to show that weak-* convergence does not imply weak convergence with an explicit example. Here are the definitions I adopt:
"A sequence $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ converges weakly to $x$ in $X$ if for all $f\in X'$, $f(x_n)\to f(x)$ in $\mathbb F$ as $n\to\infty.$
A sequence $(f_n)_{n=1}^\infty\subset X'$ (bounded linear functionals) converges weak-* to $f$ in $X'$ if for all $x\in X$, $f_n(x)\to f(x)$ in $\mathbb F$ as $n\to\infty.$"
Fix $X = l^{1}$, claim: the Schauder basis $(e_n)$ does not converge weakly to $0$ but converges weakly* to $0$ in $X$.
For the first assertion, note that a representation of the linear functional in $X'$ is
$f((x_n)) =  \sum \alpha_n y_n$ with $y_n \in l^{\infty}$, pick $y_n = (-1)^{n}$, $f((e_n))$ does not even converge.
For the second assertion, note that $(c^{0})'\cong X$ where $(c^{0})$ stands for the space of convergent sequence that vanishes. A sequence $(g_n)_{n=1}^\infty\subset (c^{0})'$ converges weak-* to $g$ in $(c^{0})$ if for all $x\in (c^{0})$, $g_n(x)\to g(x)$ in $\mathbb F$ as $n\to\infty.$ Note that the isomorphism $(c^{0})\cong X$ sends $(e_n)$ to a series of linear operators $g_n$ such that $g_n(e_n) = 1 \text{ and } g_n(e_m)=0$ for $n \ne m$, and for $g_n \in (c^{0})$ $g_n((z)) = \sum \beta_n f_n(e_n)$. As $\beta_n$ is the tail part of a convergent sequence that vanishes it must converge to $0$. Therefore $(e_n)$ converges weakly* in $X$.
Now my questions are:
(i) Is the above proof correct? (It seems to me that in proofs regarding duality, the biggest obstacle is usually nomenclature...)
(ii) Are there any other simple examples showing weak-* convergence does not imply weak convergence? (I guess for $L^{p}$ spaces there will be many examples).
(iii) Is being "reflexive" ($X \cong X''$) the necessary and sufficient condition of (weak-* convergence being equivalent to weak convergence)? In that case, I shall have a large class of counterexamples.
(iv) Based on (iii), can we assert that the fundamental reason of "converges weakly*" being weaker is because $X$ is usually a subspace of $X''$ (or embedded into $X''$), and all these definitions are coined to reflect it?
*** As there are votes to close this question, the focus of the above questions should be (iii) and (iv).

Clarification 1: reflexive does not simply mean that $X\simeq X''$ but, more concretely, that the canonical embedding of $X$ in $X''$ is surjective. The distinction is important because there are examples of non-reflexive Banach spaces $X$ with $X\simeq X''$.
Clarification 2: you defined weak and weak$^*$ convergence for sequences, but to discuss reflexivity one needs to consider the respective topologies, and convergence of sequences is not enough for that, you need nets. For instance, when one says that $X$ is dense in $X^{**}$, what this means is that any element of $X^{**}$ is the limit (in the weak$^*$ topology) of a net in $X$.
One thing that is muddied a bit by the example you used (because the canonical basis exists in $c_0$ and $\ell^1$ and $\ell^\infty$), is that one considers the weak topology on a normed space, while the weak$^*$ topology is considered on the dual of a normed space. So to ask whether they are the same you should be asking on $X^*$.
With the above in mind, it is indeed true that  $X$ is reflexive if and only if the weak and weak$^*$ topologies agree on $X^*$. This is because the dual of $(X^*,\text{weak}^*)$ is $X$; if both topologies agree then $X$ is the dual of $(X^*,\text{weak})$, which is $X^{**}$.
